# My website might have problems being indexed by Google bots?

Tags: web-crawler

http://ptcsavjetovaliste.org and I think because it is in Croatian language it might have problems being indexed because of letters like čćžšđ?!
Look at the crawler errors I see in Webmaster tools... http://i257.photobucket.com/albums/hh225/TitoChe1/crawlers.jpg
P.S. I submitted my sitemap and site to google and installed Google analytics....
Please tell me if I have a problem to be indexed because of my code? 
I offer to promote anyone that helps me on this site which is the first counselling centre in Sarajevo.

Answer (score 1):

you site loads realy slow  and google shows a timeout error. It has nothing to do with the chars you use.